# Calculating perimeter of contours (OpenCV, Python)

Tags: python, opencv, computer-vision

I have this image here with lots of small printer dots in the color cyan, magenta and yellow.

After separating the color channel (CMYK) I applied a threshold on the image.

Here for the color channel cyan.

[image]

Now I want to find a way to calculate the perimeter for each of these dots.
So in the end I want to have a mean and standard deviation for the perimeter.

I already found a way (with the help from someone here on stackoverflow) to compute the mean and std dev for the sizes of the dots with:

```
def compute_mean_stddev(contours_of_images):
    for contours_of_image in contours_of_images:
        count = len(contours_of_image)

        sum_list = []
        for cntr in contours_of_image:
            area = cv2.contourArea(cntr) 
            sum_list.append(area) 
            
        average = np.mean(sum_list)
        standard_deviation = np.std(sum_list)
```

Instead now for the area, is there a way to get the perimeter?

Comment: For what you want the area and perimeter? will you train a neural network? or another classifier?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Nice case, according to the [OpenCV documentation](https://docs.opencv.org/4.x/dd/d49/tutorial_py_contour_features.html) once you have the contours you should be able to calculate what you want using `cv.arcLength()` method.

> It is also called arc length. It can be found out using cv.arcLength() function. Second argument specify whether shape is a closed contour (if passed True), or just a curve.

Exampe from official docs:

```
    import numpy as np
    import cv2 as cv
    img = cv.imread('star.jpg',0)
    ret, thresh = cv.threshold(img,127,255,0)
    contours, hierarchy = cv.findContours(thresh, 1, 2)
    
    cnt = contours[0]
    area = cv.contourArea()  # Area of first contour
    perimeter = cv.arcLength(cnt, True)  # Perimeter of first contour
```

So in your case you should be update your code as follows:

```
    def compute_mean_stddev(contours_of_images):
        for contours_of_image in contours_of_images:
            count = len(contours_of_image)

            sum_list = []
            for cntr in contours_of_image:
                area = cv2.contourArea(cntr)
                perimeter = cv.arcLength(cntr, True)  
            
            average = np.mean(sum_list)
            standard_deviation = np.std(sum_list)
```

I hope this works!